# Find the last word of a sentence SQL

Tags: sql, string, oracle

I'm trying to return a table that contains all the employees who do have the first name starting with an 'A' and the surname starting with a 'R', from the tables 'dep' and 'emp'. I tried to use the INDEXOF function but seems it doesn't work . what can I do?

```
select emp.nome,emp.sal,emp.ndep,dep.nome, 
from emp, dep 
where (substring(emp.nome,1,indexof(' ',emp.nome)))like 'A%' 
and (substring(emp.nome,lastindexof(' ',emp.nome),emp.nome.lenght)) like 'R%'
order by 1
```

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  Sample data and desired results would also help.

Comment: What database? Smells like oracle.. SQL is just a standard, and most DBs aren't standard when it comes to string handling

Comment: No join condition?!? Tip of today: Switch to modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax! Easier to write (without errors), easier to read and maintain, and easier to convert to outer join if needed.

Comment: Yes, I'm sorry, it's Oracle database. The guy who answered above already solved my issue. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no point doing the first substring, as a string 'ABC DEF' is like 'A%' whether or not you cut the bit off after the space.

The surname, your use of lastindexof causes the space to become part of the name because you forgot to add 1 to skip onto the next character after the space, and `' RST'` is never like `'R%'`. I swapped your lastindexof to instr, because I wasn't sure if lastindexof is as universally applicable as instr. calling instr with a  negative start index causes it to search backward from the end of the string

```
select emp.nome,emp.sal,emp.ndep,dep.nome, 
from 
  emp 
  INNER JOIN dep ON /*something_goes_here*/
where emp.nome like 'A%' and 
 SUBSTR(emp.nome, INSTR(emp.nome, ' ', -1) + 1,emp.nome.length)) like 'R%'
order by 1
```

You need to finish the query off by putting a clause in describing how the tables should be joined

Answer (score 0):

I would expect a condition like this:

```
where nom like 'A% R%'
```

assuming that `nom` has both the first name and last name.

Comment: And hopefully no one called Admiral Gordon Romeo Linoff ;)